# Random Walk why is $E[X_{t}] = \mu t$

Tags: time-series, expected-value, random-walk

**Question**

A Random Walk can be defined as follows. $Z_t$ ($t=1,2,3,\ldots$) is a noise term with a Normal$(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution.  Define $X_0=0$ and

$$X_t = X_{t-1}+Z_t$$

for $t=1,2,3,\ldots.$

I encountered this expression:

$$E[X_t] = E\left[\sum_{i=1}^t Z_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^t E[Z_i] = \mu t.$$

I do not really understand why the sum of expectations of $Z_i$ becomes  $\mu t.$ Could someone tell me why? For me, it does not really make sense to take an expectation of a single value, $Z_i.$ Is it equal to $\mu$?

Comment: You defined Z_t to be distributed normally with mean (or expected value) mu. So yeah E[Z_i] = /mu according to your definition

Comment: Please include your equations using MathJax rather than posting images.

Comment: @ThePointer I really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the linearity of expectation. $X_t$ can be written as sum of consecutive steps of mean $\mu$, and if you take $t$ steps, the mean will be $\mu t$. It's like the expected total distance of a man after some time $t$, who takes $\mu$ steps at each move.

P.S. note the starting condition, $X_1=Z_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the definition of $Z_t$ and particularly with its mean $\mu$. If $\mu\neq 0$, what you get is random walk with drift. The regular vanilla random walk uses $Z_t$ with $\mu=0$. The corresponding expectation of the random walk at time $t$ is then zero. On the other hand, for a random walk with drift it is $\mu t$ just as you noted.